# Does an SQLite database offer additional security in comparison with Files in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-file, database-security

I am making an Android application and need to decide what type of data storage method to use. The size of the data I need to store is fairly small and therefore I was thinking of storing my data in a JSON format and saving it to a file internally.

I want to protect the data I am storing and was wondering if using an SQLite database adds any additional security in comparison with that a file has? The online [Android resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) states that both internal file storage and an SQLite Database are only accessible to the application they were created by and doesn't introduce either as being dominant in terms of security. Would anyone be able to help with some useful information?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Only that you can't open it with a text editor. And normally it's stored in the application workspace, so only rooted users can find and access it. And you could cypher it by using something like SQLCipher

Comment: Thank you @Rotwang, that's very helpful.